# Custom renderer for custom customer address attribute

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, adminhtml, customer-address, customer-attribute

I was able to add 2 custom  address attributes successfully  but these attributes are dependent on each other .

now I am facing an issue with updating customer address from adminhtml , I need to add some ajax ability to these 2 attributes

I looked for an example out there that shows custom renderer and found only examples for catalog attributes and they didn't work for customer address attributes

do you have any example ? or the idea is not doable ?